# Ajax post request doesn't work (simple)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am struggling to make a simple ajax request. I have no idea why it doesn't work.

```js
<script>
function checkdata()  {
  var reqdata = "aha"; 
  alert(reqdata);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://example.com/cs/test.php",
    data: reqdata,
    cache: false,
    success: function(returnedata) {
      alert(returnedata);
    }
  }); //end of ajax
  return true;
}
</script>
```

```html
<input type="button" value="CheckData" onclick="checkdata();">
```

The file https://example.com/cs/test.php has one:  echo "done"; which works properly. When I navigate to the page with the browser I see just "Done"

What is the problem here? Thanks.

Comment: Open your browser console and look for errors.  Do you actually call this function?

Comment: if the url is not same domain, it's probably a CORS issue - your developer tools console would let you know

Comment: It is the same domain ...  but where toi find the developer tools. Google chrome doesn't show anything.

Comment: @Brana hit F12.

Comment: I got it .. I get this error:  $ is not defined

Comment: That means that you haven't loaded jQuery before you call it

Comment: @Brana Jquery's not defined. Did you add it to the page?

Comment: I think there was, as I had 2 ajax request on longer page, but  on the example page there wasn't. And the first worked and second (this one) didn't.

Comment: the error says: XMLHttpRequest cannot load example.com/cs/test.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'example.com'; is therefore not allowed access

Comment: It seems http and https from the same domain are not consididered the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to include `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js`

your code will not work without this

Comment: I have it in the page - the error  says: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com/cs/test.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access

Comment: @Brana That means you are trying to access it from a different domain.

Comment: the url is the place u send the data to ,
use you post data url for example 
u hae a page named test
so url will go to test page

Comment: It is the same domain it seem that htacess has been redirecting the page from https to http. But should work now.

Answer (score -3):

here is something that worked ,, change your function declaration to match this

```
checkdata = function () {
var reqdata = "aha";
....
```

Comment: That shouldn't change anything

Comment: `checkdata = function` and `function checkdata` are the same thing

Comment: did you two even try to run the code ,, i tried this on https://jsfiddle.net/   go check yourselves the alert wasn`t working and now it does i appreciate the unvote ..

Comment: Did you even look at the comment from the OP that explained what the actual error was rather than just assuming?

Comment: i`m not an expert but the declaration used in the question doesn`t work either in snippet or jsfiddle enlighten me why

Comment: open the site and copy the  html and javascript each to its place -> run -> press button -> check console

Comment: @ModarNa I tried it on a private server, and it worked both ways, however as you described, only the second works on jsfiddle. I assume jsFiddle uses the `new Function(<code>)()` way to evaluate the code and not simply `eval`, thus putting everything in a scope, which would explain why using a global variable changes it.

Comment: For me even the code snippet posted in the question shows the same error and assuming that this errors are trivial there is hundreds of questions posted here the answear was a missing syntax